# How would I redirect /foo to /wiki/foo

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

I used the Short URL generator from [Redwerks](http://shorturls.redwerks.org/) to create my .htaccess file. So now if a user types in **foobar.org/wiki/foo** they are taken to the correct page, however if they type in **foobar.org/foo** they are given an error page. How can I make **/foo** redirect to **/wiki/foo**?

Here's the contents of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wiki/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wiki/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I'm now getting a "500 Internal Server Error" when changing the first rule to this.

Comment: Still getting a 500 error, but this time it's giving me the error no matter whether I manually put in /wiki/ or not.

Comment: ok check your Apache error.log and tell what the exact error is.

Comment: "Mon Sep 08 17:01:09.231693 2014] [core:error] [pid 20805] [client] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."